# Posting JSON to server returns empty response, but it works perfectly in Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2

So my **login.php** script is working just fine when sending request as raw JSON in Postman, but sending it in Android returns empty response, and when I try to cast it to **UserResponse** in **update()** method I get 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.alenpersic.hrvend.Entities.UserResponse.getMessage()' on a null object reference' error.
[postman_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13We7.png)

This is inside my **MainActivity.java**

```
     @Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg){
    UserResponse response = (UserResponse) arg;
    Toast.makeText(this, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (response.getMessage().equals("Login successful.")){
         Toast.makeText(this, "Prijava uspješna!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         showMachineList();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pogrešno korisničko ime i lozinka!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    DataObservable.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
    showMachineList();
}

public void SignUp (View view){
    User currentUser = new User(usernameEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString());
    DataObservable.getInstance().addObserver(this);
    LoginLoader controller = new LoginLoader();
    controller.loadUser(controller.create(), currentUser);
}
```

**WebServiceInterface.java**

```
public interface WebServiceInterface {

@GET("machine/read.php")
Call<MachineResponse> getMachines();

@GET("machine/read_materials.php")
Call<RawMaterialsResponse> getRawMaterials(
        @Query("id") String id
);

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("login.php")
Call<LoginResponse> sendUser(
        @Body User user
);
```

**LoginLoader.java**

```
public class LoginLoader extends DataLoader {

public void loadUser(WebServiceInterface webserviceInterface, User user)
{
    Call<LoginResponse> call = webserviceInterface.sendUser(user);
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, retrofit2.Response response)
{
    if(response.isSuccessful())
    {
        LoginResponse loginResponse = (LoginResponse) response.body();
        UserResponse data = loginResponse.getData();
        DataObservable.getInstance().notifyObserverWithResponse(data);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", response.errorBody().toString() + " " + response.message() + " " + response.raw());
    }
}
```

**LoginResponse.java**

```
public class LoginResponse extends DataResponse {
UserResponse data;

public UserResponse getData(){
    return data;
}

public void setData(UserResponse data){
    this.data = data;
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setMessage(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Comment: Would help if you have an example of the json and check if Retrofit actually receives what your expecting. I know postman adds some headers by default that sometimes servers cannot cope without. Retrofit doesn't do this, hence you might be getting something unexpected.

Comment: I added screenshot with the example of the JSON I am sending. How would I check if retrofit received what I am expecting?

Comment: I'd use this [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/README.md)

Comment: So after adding the logging interceptor, I noticed that the response is NOT empty. Moreover, it's just like it should be [see here](https://i.imgur.com/1TD3orv.png). But I still don't know why does the **update()** method say it's null :/

Comment: On the image you posted I can't really see the field `data`. Is it there? Also, are you running this with proguard enabled?

Comment: @Fred, you were on the right track! After reading the documentation for a bit, I noticed that `Call<T>` parses the response depending on the class you pass, so instead of `Call<LoginResponse>`, I had to use `Call<UserResponse>`. The program was probably looking for a `data` field but could't find it (just like you mentioned). Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I manage to help you out!